# Output user input in PL/SQL using SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi everyone I'm new to PL/SQL ,however I'm wrting a small code that a prompt a user to input a 2 numbers and display the numbers using DBMS_output.Put_line .
but I get a compilation error ,below is my code ,I'm using "Oracle SQL developer"

`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;`

`DECLARE
 n_no_1 number(8,2);
 n_no_2 number(8,2);
 BEGIN`

`DBMS_output.put_line('Enter Value for no 1');
&n_no_1;
DBMS_output.put_line('Enter value for no 2');
&n_no_2;`

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The value of No 1 is' || n_no_1 );`

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The value of No 2 is' || n_no_2 );`

`END;`

`/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 lines are your problem, however, not for the reasons mentioned in other answer:

`&n_no_1;`

`&n_no_2;`

In SQL, you can use the ampersand (&) to trigger something called "Macro substitution".

When the compiler comes across something like this (ie `&n_no1`), it prompts the user to input a value for it to substitute in it's place.

So if you enter "Hello". Your code becomes:

```
DBMS_output.put_line('Enter Value for no 1');
Hello;
```

And as you can see, that would fail, if you had just typed that out.

What you want to do is to assign that value to a variable, like this:

```
n_no_1 := '&n_no_1';
```

That gets "replaced" by this:

```
n_no_1 := 'Hello';
```

which compiles - and runs - just fine.

That all said, this is NOT the best way to do this, although this appears to be a learning excercise ?

Look up the `PROMPT` and `ACCEPT` keywords .. you can use those in SQL (outside your BEGIN / DECLARE / END block) to capture the values first in a neater fashion :)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm#SQPUG052

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#SQPUG026

Found an additional link here worth a good read. Explains a lot more than what you're looking at, but it discusses substitution variables, and other similiar things (and some other unrelated things :) )

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia

Comment: the compilation now is successfuly I change the code little bit but I don't get the out put ? this the code now `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
DECLARE
n_number1 number(8,2):=&n_number1;
n_number2 number(8,2):=&n_number2;
 BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n_number1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n_number2);
END;
/`

Comment: Sorry Ditto, but that is wrong from the very beginning. "Macro substitution" is not "in SQL." Macro substitution is a feature of SQLPlus and other front-ends based on it, such as SQL Developer. The substitution is made BEFORE SQL Developer submits a text string (the PL/SQL program) to the interpreter ("compiler") for processing. Matthew's answer is correct and yours is incorrect.

Comment: @ditto this is what I did before the begin and now is working `n_number1 number(8,2):=&n_number1;`

Answer (score -1):

The `&variable` syntax is not PL/SQL: it is part of SQL Developer.  I see what you are trying to do and syntax errors, but there's no point in correcting them because it's not going to work in the end.

The reason is: you cannot accept user input via PL/SQL at runtime.

Comment: I agree with you about `&` syntax is not part of the PL/SQL,but in this tutorial I can see that it access user input via sql developer  you can run the first code and see http://www.plsqltutorial.com/plsql-nested-block/

Comment: "The reason is: you cannot accept user input via PL/SQL."  sorry, this isn't entirely true. Macro substitution allows you to "accept user input via PL/SQL" just fine.  It's not pretty, but it does allow you.

Comment: They are using the `&` syntax of their client (e.g., SQL Developer) to collect and set the value _at compile time_.  In your example, it looks like you are trying to collect the user input _at runtime_.  In an anonymous PL/SQL block, compile time and runtime may be very close to one another, but there _is_ a difference.

Comment: The main point is that the substitution is processed by the client program (SQLPlus or SQLDeveloper etc.) **before** a text stream (the procedure or function, with the substitution already performed) is sent to the PL/SQL interpreter. Your answer is 100% correct. The PL/SQL processor itself, if it could be accessed directly, would have no idea what to do with `&`.